# Accessing elements inside dialog in fragments

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog

I want to access my spinner element which i have placed inside dialog in my fragment .
But the application crashes and causes null pointer exception whenever the button is clicked. I want to access views of dialog in onclick listener of the button

```
public class Plan extends Fragment {

Button add;
Button can;
Spinner spin;
View view;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plan, container, false);

    add = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.bAddPlan);

    //addItemsOnSpinner(view);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Add Materials ");

            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

            alertDialogBuilder
                .setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null))
                .setPositiveButton("Add",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                    }
                  })

                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });


                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                spin = (Spinner)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

                alertDialog.show();


        }
    });


    return view;

}



@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}
```

}

Comment: Where is stack trace ? Give it.

Comment: Next time please add more tags